# Toilet water input tube getting dislodged

Tags: water, toilet, hose

[image]

The input water hose in my toilet tank keeps getting dislodged. The pressure of the water coming out of the hose pushes it out at the canister it should fit into. I have heard that there should be some sort of clip to hold the hose in place but I’m on familiar with the term I should use when I go to the hardware store -how do I ask for such a clip? Also I’ve been told that the hose itself may have gotten stiff over time and I could replace the hose, but how do I know what diameter? what do I ask for?  THANK YOU SOOOO MUCH!!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no separate replacement clip nor specific hose. Of course, yours doesn't use a clip anyway and would only be included with a whole new fill valve assembly.

But, you may be able to remove the hose and take it to the Hardware, Automotive or Aquarium store for a replacement...a tiny bit thicker or fatter is ideal. Just be careful, you're dealing with that plastic garbage and aged plastic can snap.

Otherwise, with your situation. I've done very well with a 1/4" or more length of drinking straw, some fine sandpaper, tinfoil or just tape wrapped around the end of the hose. It makes for a much snugger fit for the hose to be re-secured in its hole.